# Validity index for non convex clusters

Tags: clustering, unsupervised-learning

I'm trying to measure clustering methods on unsupervised data.

Among others, I'm using DBSCAN which can find non centered clusters.
Is there any internal cluster validity index fitted for non-convex clusters?

Answer (score 2):

There was one recently proposed:

- Moulavi, D., Jaskowiak, P. A., Campello, R. J. G. B., Zimek, A., & Sander, J. (2014).
   **Density-based clustering validation.**
   In Proceedings of the 14th SIAM International Conference on Data Mining (SDM), Philadelphia, PA.

Havn't read it in details yet, or tried it.